# How do we can use the live MongoDB database in the local system | MongoDB | Database backup

Tags: linux, database, mongodb

I have a project which deploys on the Linux-based os hosting server. Due to some reason, I am not able to start MongoDB.

Error

> about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for
> connections. forked process: 18084 ERROR: child process failed, exited
> with 100 To see additional information in this output, start without
> the "--fork" option.

I search a lot of tutorials but no success. Even the hosting provider suggests to re-install the MongoDB.
So I have decided to back up the data and use it in my local system.

But I didn't know how we can do that. What I did is copy the "/var/lib/mongo" content and download that folder in my local system.

So how can I use this downloaded content of the MongoDB folder in my local system to use as a backup for the live data?

As because MongoDB is not able to run on the live server can someone also tell me how can I backup the database(obviously the above approach is not the ideal solution). I am going to re-install the MongoDB on the server but I need the data.

FYI my local system in window 10.

Comment: One reason why your MongoDB server is not starting because of improper earlier shutdowns. Check this once: https://mkyong.com/mongodb/old-lock-file-datadbmongod-lock-probably-means-unclean-shutdown/

Comment: If I run the command with repair flag. there is any chance I can lose some data?

Comment: There is a warning _"Only use `mongod --repair` if you have no other options. The operation removes and does not save any corrupt data during the repair process"_ in MongoDB website: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/ so just delete the lock file and try restarting `mongos`

Comment: Did you check the log file? Typically you find it in /var/log/mongodb

Comment: If your provider recommends to reinstall MongoDB then you should change your provider.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. When you are not able to start the MongoDB (at least once) then it does not contain any data, thus a backup is useless because it would be empty anyway.

Comment: How did you try to start the MongoDB?

Comment: I have checked the log and there is nothing. the MongoDB was working the day before yesterday but not working from today. So I am not able to restart the MongoDB. Maybe the server reboot automatically which causes the problem. But really I have the live data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the problem is with the MongoDB. The database was working 2-3 days back. suddenly it stops working.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have checked the log and there is nothing"? That's not possible, even at normal operation you get tons of logs.